# Add Capabilities to Custom Post Type after it has been created

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, user-roles, security, capabilities

I have a custom post type that is created by an external plugin. This plugin uses the capabilities associated with posts. I want to add my own custom capabilities to this post type. I have seen plenty of examples of how to do this when registering a new post type but I can't add the capabilities at this point as otherwise the custom capabilities won't be there when I next update the plugin.

What would be the best way to add the capabilities after the custom post type has been created?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Irrespective of the plugin you use > each plugin will give you an option to save / view the PHP code generated for the custom post type. This code will also include the capabilities added and generated by the plugin. All you need to do is copy this code into your functions.php and before that disable the plugin. So the custom post type stays and now you can play around with the code / capabilities of the custom post type.